# URL point sub folder not working in Joomla2.5

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, joomla2.5

I want new domain to point existing site sub folder of joomla2.5

```
      for example: http://olddomain.com/subfolder  is working but
      http://newdomain.com is not working
```

I have tried

```
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine on
        rewriterule ^subfolder/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

but not working
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I have got similar problem when I migrated from version 1.5 to 2.5. In my case, http://domain.com/index.php/subfolder worked but http://domain.com/subfolder did not.
It must related to SEF and mod_rewrite and your .htaccess.
In my case, I am still unsuccessful to solve it, still using index.php in url. I would like to see the solution. So, it might be the same, try it with index.php.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to change the DNS entry for newdomain.com and let it point to the subfolder directly.

Answer (score 0):

Move the files to the right location, it's really not meaningful to fool apache on every request and moving stuff around, you're really looking for trouble here.

Maybe you should clear the cache? check the configuration.php for wrong paths? set up a fresh .htaccess?